# If six different balls are placed in three different boxes, what is the probability that exactly two balls are placed in the first box?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If six different balls are placed in three different boxes, what is the probability that exactly two balls are placed in the first box?

My attempt: $k_1+k_2+k_3=6$, $k_i$ - quantity of balls in $i$ box. $k_1=2$ hence there are 4 sets for $k_2, k_3:$ $\{0,4\},\{1,3\},\{3,1\},\{4,0\}$.
Adding set $\{2,2\}$ we get all combinations when there are 2 balls in the first box $\Rightarrow$ possibility $= \frac{4}{5}$?

Comment: Are you asking what the probability is that two balls are placed in the first box if six balls are distributed to three boxes?

Comment: yes, I do. English isn't my native language, hence sometime my states are bad to uderstand

Comment: yes. Let's say they have numbers from 1 to 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3^6$ ways to distribute six balls to three boxes since there are three choices for each of the six balls.

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select exactly two of the six balls to be placed in the first box and $2$ ways to select the box in which each of the four remaining balls is placed.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{6}{2}2^4$$
favorable cases.

Therefore, the probability that exactly two balls are placed in the first box when six balls are distributed to three different boxes is 
$$\frac{\binom{6}{2}2^4}{3^6}$$

**Note:**  You attempted to count cases by considering how many balls are placed in each box.  However, the 
$$\binom{6 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{8}{2}$$ 
solutions to the equation 
$$k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 6$$
in the nonnegative integers are not equally likely to occur.  There is only one way to place all six balls in the first box.  However, there are 
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} = 90$$
ways to place two balls in each box.

Comment: +1 nice answerTaussig as usual...I did this at the numerator $\binom{6}{2}(\binom{4}{0}+\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{4})=2^4\binom{6}{2}$

Comment: @Isham  That works.  The number of subsets of a set with $n$ elements is $2^n$ since each element is either included or not included in a subset.  Hence, a set with four elements has $2^4$ subsets.  The number of subsets of size $k$ of a set with $n$ elements is $\binom{n}{k}$.  Since the number of elements in a subset of a four-element set ranges from $0$ to $4$, $$\binom{4}{0} + \binom{4}{1} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{3} + \binom{4}{4} = 2^4$$

Comment: Yes it was easier for me that way...Then I used Newton's binomial..